# jTDS 1.3.1 and SQL Server 2014+

Tags: sql-server, jtds

According to http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

"jTDS is an open source 100% pure Java (type 4) JDBC 3.0 driver for Microsoft SQL Server (6.5, 7, 2000, 2005, 2008 and 2012)..."

But when I perform a Google search for "jtds sql server 2016" I get quite a few hits, including this page telling me that it's compatible with SQL Server 2000-2016

https://www.dbvis.com/features/sqlserver-database-drivers/

Does anyone know the definitive answer? Can I use jTDS 1.3.1 (which appears to be latest) against a SQL server > 2012?

Comment: All SQL Servers are compatible with earlier versions of the TDS protocol, so even very old clients can connect to, say, SQL Server 2016. The only problems can happen when data types are involved that downlevel clients do not support (like `DATETIME2` and `DATETIMEOFFSET`), but that's not an issue for clients that support up to 2012, as no new types have been introduced since then. So yes, it should work fine. Having said that, for greenfield projects it is worth looking at Microsoft's own native JDBC driver for SQL Server, as it's no longer the inferior option it used to be.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeroen.

Comment: i am facing similar issue - when i use jtds1.3.1 for 2019 it gives error like WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.jtds-1_3_1_jar (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.eFpXADS, service jboss.driver-demander.java:/jdbc/eFpDataSource]  always. any idea ?

Comment: @WitWikky you might need to raise a new question for that one.